# Name keyword in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Why is this working or better yet what does it represent ( replace table with an existing one )

```
select table.name from table
```

and where is it documented ( postgresql ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select table.name from table
```

is equivalent to

```
select name(table) from table
```

which, since `name` is a type, is equivalent to

```
select cast(table as name) from table
```

The first `table` is a row variable containing all the columns from the respective table, so you will get a text representation of the row.

This is not directly documented, since it's a combination of several obscure features (some dating back to PostQUEL).  In fact, this usage has been disallowed in PostgreSQL 9.1 (see the [release notes](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/release-9-1.html) under "Casting").

Answer (score 1):

The name type is documented in the string types. Hidden columns are documented (off the top of my head) in the section on system catalogs, or in the internals.

You can see hidden columns in pg_attribute. Their numbers are negative:

```
select attum, attname
from pg_attribute
where attrelid = 'yourtable'::regclass
```

That should reveal xmin, xmax, ctid, oid (where applicable), etc. Might this also yield name? (I can't test on the iPad.)

Comment: +1 for stating that a fly Stack Overflow user accesses SO via iPad! :D

Comment: @mu: naw, tis only so occasional. :-)